# How to scrape data from a website and store in folders in a hierarchical stucture using python script?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to fetch data from a website using python, I have locally downloaded the text file then, I want to fetch the data from an anchor tag inside the text file and make a new folder renamed as the anchor tag value.

Here I am making new folders using python but unable to fetch the data from the txt file and process

I am able to make new folders but i want the rename as the anchor tag value

```
import os

root_path = '/home'    
folders = ['folder 01', 'folder 02', 'folder 03']    
for folder in folders:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path, folder))
```

Comment: can you provide the text file, and what your expected output should be? For example, what folders are you trying to create? It sounds like all you need to do is parse the text file (I'm assuming you mean HTML??) and pull the tags you want into a list. Then you can use that list as your `folders` variable for your loop

Comment: yes the file is an html file  till now i have tried taken an file and extracted the anchor tags in that wich is smothing like  a  b   c   c   d now i want to save this result in an array so that i can use the above code to rename folders

Comment: You have the right idea.  you'll need to use beautifulsoup to parse the html , find those tags that you're looking for. You'll most likely use `find_all()`, but to what capacity I don't know without seeing what the actual html is and identifying specifically how to find those tags.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code.It should create all folders name present in anchor tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os
url = 'Url Here'
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for folder in soup.find_all('a'):
    root_path = '/home'
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path, folder.text))
```

Please let me know if this work.